# How to overwrite/update a collection in Azure Cosmos DB from Databrick/PySpark

Tags: pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have the following PySpark code written on Databricks Notebook that sucessfully saves the results from the sparkSQL to Azure Cosmos DB with the line of code:

```
df.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").mode("overwrite").options(**writeConfig3).save()
```

The complete code is as follows:

```
test = spark.sql("""SELECT
  Sales.CustomerID AS pattersonID1
 ,Sales.InvoiceNumber AS myinvoicenr1
FROM Sales
limit 4""")


## my personal cosmos DB
writeConfig3 = {
    "Endpoint": "https://<cosmosdb-account>.documents.azure.com:443/",
    "Masterkey": "<key>==",
    "Database": "mydatabase",
    "Collection": "mycontainer",
    "Upsert": "true"
}

df = test.coalesce(1)

df.write.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").mode("overwrite").options(**writeConfig3).save()
```

Using the above code I have successfully written to my Cosmos DB database (mydatabase) and collection (mycontainer) 
[image]

When I try to overwrite the container with by changing SparkSQL with the following(just changing pattersonID1 to pattersonID2, and myinvoicenr1 to myinvoicenr2

```
test = spark.sql("""SELECT
  Sales.CustomerID AS pattersonID2
 ,Sales.InvoiceNumber AS myinvoicenr2
FROM Sales
limit 4""")
```

Instead overwriting/updating the collection with the new query Cosmos DB appends the container as follows:

[image]

And still leaves the original query in the collection:

[image]

Is there a way to completely overwrite or update cosmos DB?

Comment: Yikes - you just embedded your Cosmos DB key and shared it to the world. Please regenerate your key asap. I edited both the account name and they key out of your question, but anyone with sufficient rep can see the revision history.

Comment: Thanks David, the key has been re-generated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that documents have a unique `id` (something you never specified, and is therefore auto-generated for you as a guid). When you write your new document, you've just renamed one of the non-`id`, non-unique properties, `pattersonID1`, to `pattersonID2`, and it's just creating a new document, as expected. There's no possible way to know that this new document is related to the original, since it's a completely new document, with its own set of properties.

You can update existing documents, by querying them (or reading them), modifying them, and then replacing them. Or you can choose to query for old documents and delete them (one by one, or a transactionally as a batch of deletes within a partition, via stored procedure). Lastly, you can delete and re-create a container, which will remove all documents currently stored in it.

Comment: oh I see. I never thought of id - good catch. Is there a link showing how to update an existing document/collection?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of use Spark to Cosmos DB Connector, you can use the Azure Cosmos DB SQL API SDK for Python to manage databases and the JSON documents they contain in this NoSQL database service:

> - Create Cosmos DB databases and modify their settings
> - Create and modify containers to store collections of JSON documents
> - Create, read, update, and delete the items (JSON documents) in your containers
> - Query the documents in your database using SQL-like syntax.

[Azure Cosmos DB SQL API client library for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-python/blob/master/README.md)